# Re-enable "this project is out of date" Dialog Box

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

How do I re-enable the "this project is out of date" Dialog Box in Visual Studio 2013 Professional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch it back on at Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run.

There first option showing a combobox is "On Run, when projects are out of date:".
There you have to select "Prompt to build".

See also:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/8263/the-setting-on-run-when-projects-out-of-date-has-n.html